# Can't split 24bit flac files on the command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, flac

I am trying to export a 24bit flac file in my ubuntu terminal. I've tried two different methods, but neither work.

Method 1: shntool

when I run this command:
`shntool split -f times.cue -O always -o lowq_full_silence.flac`

where lowq_full_silence.flac  was rendered in audacity as a flac file with level=0 and bit depth=16 bit, my command works.

but if i run this command:

`shntool split -f times.cue -O always -o full_hq.flac`

where full_hq.flac has level=8 and bit depth=24 bit
The command fails:

```
shntool [split]: warning: unsupported format 0xfffe (Unknown) while processing file: [full_hq.flac]
shntool [split]: error: cannot continue due to error(s) shown above
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shntool/+bug/2000794

Method 2: ffmpeg

Trying to split the flac file with comma separated 'split points' input

`ffmpeg -i "full_hq.flac" -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_times "22,441,556,559" "%d_output.flac"`

But the output from this ffmpeg command has broken length metadata:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4905

Is there a better way to split a high quality 24bit flac file into individual segments, where each exported segment file has correct length metadata?

Files:
https://file.io/lvGTUEgQArb7